# ¿Cómo redirigir 10% del tráfico a un sitio y 90% a otro de manera aleatoria?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

¿Alguien me podría decir si es posible hacer esto? El planteo es el siguiente: Tengo un sitio A, B y C.

Los usuarios ingresaran al sitio A y serán automáticamente redirigidos (301), pero quiero que el 90% vaya al sitio B y el 10% al sitio C.

Las probabilidades de redirección deben ser totalmente aleatorias, sin preferencia.

¿Existe alguna forma de realizar esto? Gracias de antemano!

Comment: ¿En qué momento y bajo que condiciones sabrías que ya tienes al 100% de tus usuarios y a partir de ahi comenzar a redirigir?

Comment: Mi idea era compartir el enlace del sitio A, cuando la gente haga click ingresará al sitio C que cargará un script que redirigirá automáticamente al 90% de los usuarios al sitio B y al otro 10% al sitio C. Espero haberme podido explicar con claridad.

Comment: Yo creo que es importante saber a que te refieres con sitios A, B, C y lo que estas interpretando como sitio, una seccion de un mismo dominio eje, `domain.com/A`, `domain.com/B` o `domain.com`, `domainB.com` ; en cualquiera de los casos es muy difícil saber el 100% de tus usuarios como menciona BetaM, en resumen: si el enlace de tu sitio lo tiene un único usuario ese seria tu 100%.

Comment: @Nor Con sitios me refiero a: `dominioA.com` / `dominioB.com` / `dominioC.com`, y supongamos que hay 100 usuarios que acceden al enlace `dominoA.com` por día. 90 de ellos se deberán topar con `dominioB.com` con la redirección, los restantes 10 en `dominioC.com`

Comment: Creo que lo que buscas es una probabilidad. Quieres que cuando un usuario ingrese al sitio A, tenga el 90% de probabilidad de ser redirigido al sitio B y el 10% restante de ser redirigido al sitio C. ¿Es acaso eso lo que buscas?

Comment: @MauricioContreras exacto.

Comment: Suponiendo que utilizas PHP (por la etiqueta que colocas) sería algo tan sencillo como obtener un entero aleatorio, digamos entre 0 y 99, por ejemplo: `$prob = rand(0, 99);` y luego redirigir de acuerdo al valor obtenido: `if($prob < 10) { header('Location: sitioC'); } else { header('Location: sitioB'); }`. O al menos eso intentaría hacer yo en primer lugar. La función `rand()` **no** devuelve un valor (entre los límites dados) con una [Distribución Normal](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribuci%C3%B3n_normal), por lo cual habría sesgo, excepto por la forma en que decidas calcular el 10%.

Comment: En realidad para que no exista el sesgo, deberías hacerlo creando una función que devuelva un valor con una Distribución Normal, luego ya podrías tomar tu 10% usando los valores de los extremos de tu distribución y el resto (aglomerado en el centro) sería el 90% restante. De esa forma las probabilidades de que un usuario sea redirigido al sitio B o al sitio C serán realmente de 90% y 10% respectivamente. Saludos

Comment: No necesitas hacer algo aleatorio, las conexiones de los clientes ya lo son; simplemente redirige las primeras 9 a B y la décima a C.

Comment: Las primeras 9 conexiones no tendrían una probabilidad de 90% de ser redirigidas B, tendrían una probabilidad de 100%. Lo mismo con la décima conexión, siempre tendría un 100% de probabilidad de ser redirigida a C. Si bien las conexiones son aleatorias, no sería esta aleatoriedad una con distribución normal, por lo cual al final no se cumpliría la probabilidad esperada. El OP plantea que cada conexión o petición tenga las mismas probabilidades de ser redirigidas a B o a C. O al menos es lo que yo entiendo.

Comment: @MauricioContreras pude hacerlo funcionar con tu método. En el index.php apliqué la creación de una variable random y con un `if` hice que la redirección tenga un 10% de probabilidades de ir al sitio C.

Sin embargo, la mejor opción (y más eficiente) sería poder aplicar el código en el .htaccess del sitio con Apache... no he podido desarrollar una solución efectiva, he estado buscando pero no he dado en el clavo.

Comment: Hacerlo con `.htaccess` no es trivial, se puede. Pero hay muchos pasos previos. Saludos

Comment: ¿No sería mejor utilizar un load balancer?

Comment: @Mauricio Tu apreciación es casi correcta, pero te falta tomar en cuenta el principio básico de la probabilidad: la *independencia de los eventos*. El cliente no sabe si es la conexión 9 o 10; entonces ¿Cuál es la probabilidad de ser la conexión 3? Es 1 de 10 (1/10 = 10%), ¿Cuál es la probabilidad de ser redirigdo a B? Es 9 de 10 (9/10 = 90%).

Comment: @Mauricio La distribución normal es una de varias funciones de distribución; las funciones no hacen a los eventos; es decir, no partes de la función, al contrario, las probabilidades de los eventos hacen a la función. La distribución normal no es la mas adecuada para este caso, ya que se utiliza para variables contínuas; suena mas apropiada la *Distribución de Poisson* -por mencionar alguna-, que es para variables discretas.

Comment: @Sal mejor discutir o continuar el debate en el [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30872/stack-overflow-en-espanol?_=634345385) de [es.so]. Saludos

Answer (score 3):

A esto se le llama load balance y esto no esta totalmente relacionado a la aplicacion sino a la infraestructura y del hosting ya que esto requiere saber que tanto recursos una aplicacion esta consumiendo para realizar el redireccionanimiento ademas de que esto requiere tambien evitar ciertas practicas como no utilizar la sesion en memoria ya que esto no se comparte entre servidores.

[Amazon ofrece este tipo de servicio](https://aws.amazon.com/es/elasticloadbalancing/?whats-new-cards-elb.sort-by=item.additionalFields.postDateTime&whats-new-cards-elb.sort-order=desc) y tambien [azure](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/load-balancer/?&ef_id=Cj0KCQjw_8mHBhClARIsABfFgphgJW5abABlYddjvg1WGFnozHeSALd0eHPfr6cApe-DcrVYR8H7iAcaAt_3EALw_wcB:G:s&OCID=AID2200178_SEM_Cj0KCQjw_8mHBhClARIsABfFgphgJW5abABlYddjvg1WGFnozHeSALd0eHPfr6cApe-DcrVYR8H7iAcaAt_3EALw_wcB:G:s&gclid=Cj0KCQjw_8mHBhClARIsABfFgphgJW5abABlYddjvg1WGFnozHeSALd0eHPfr6cApe-DcrVYR8H7iAcaAt_3EALw_wcB) por si quieres darle una mirada.

Answer (score 0):

pienso que si manejas backend con javascript, osea node basicamente, lo podrías hacer con una lógica que maneja una probabilidad 1/10, de la siguiente manera:

```js
//out of your controller:
const probabilities = [...new Array(9).fill(true), false];

// ...code of your controller...
if (
  probabilities[Math.round(Math.random() * (probabilities.length - 1))]
) {
  //here you can redirect the user to the page B
  console.log('ha caido en el 90%');
} else {
  //here you can redirect the user to the page C
  console.log('ha caido en el 10%');
}
// ...code of your controller...
```

Lo que estoy haciendo es crear un array que tiene 9 `true` y solo 1 `false`, y a la vez estoy accediendo a una propiedad random del array, de manera que hay una probabilidad del 90% que entre en el primer condicional y una del 10% de que entre en el segundo condicional.

De esa manera puedes enviar un res.redirect de manera random con los porcentajes que quieras :D, espero te halla servido

### Edit:

No me dí cuenta de la etiqueta de php, así que aquí te dejo la versión que adapté a php:

```
<?php
function createProbabilities(int $numerator, int $denominator)
{
    $p = [];
    for ($i = 0; $i < $numerator; $i++)
        array_push($p, false);

    for ($i = 0; $i < $denominator; $i++)
        array_push($p, true);

    return $p;
}

$probabilites = createProbabilities(1, 9);

if (rand(0, count($probabilites) - 1)) {
    echo 'Ha caido en el 90%';
} else {
    echo 'Ha caido en el 10%';
}
```

Creo que no hace falta comentar, la lógica sigue siendo la misma

Comment: Claramente está usando PHP.

Comment: @Mateo no vi la etiqueta jajajajja, ya actualizo la respuesta y trato de poner versión php, gracias por la observación!!